# Missing MSVCR100.DLL

Tags: installation, libraries, dll

While trying to install [Camstudio](http://camstudio.org/) 2.7 (Build r316), I got the following error message:

[image]

"The program can't start because MSVCR100.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem". <del>I then reinstalled the program and everything whent fine.</del>

While trying to fix the issue, I came across forum answers suggesting me do download the file from suspicious looking sites, something I refused to do. Is there some official, trustworthy way to get this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) will fix the issue. It is advisable to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999) after that.

([source](http://camstudio.org/forum/discussion/comment/5308#Comment_5308))

Comment: With recent versions of the Visual C++ Redistributables (since VS2005), security fixes can be installed without installing the prior version.