# MSVCR100.dll missing, but it is present

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, windows-installation, visual-c++

First of all, I have downloaded the runtimes suggested in the following answers:

- [MSVCR100.dll missing error even its there](https://superuser.com/questions/939051/msvcr100-dll-missing-error-even-its-there)
- [WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install](https://superuser.com/questions/885199/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install)
- [Missing MSVCR100.DLL](https://superuser.com/questions/654150/missing-msvcr100-dll)

Which are basically the same, but indicating different versions of the Visual C++ runtime. I tried all combinations of all versions of both 32 and 64 bit runtimes.

This is not a duplicate of either because the problem *still* ocurrs.

---

I have recently installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 on a new drive, but when trying to run some programs from the old drive, I get "DLL missing" errors for `MSVCR100.dll` and `MSVCP100.dll`.

My first instinct was installing the *Visual C++ Runtime Redistributable*, but this had no avail. After checking out the answers above, I found later versions of it, but the result was the same. The DLLs were appropriately placed by the installers in the `SysWOW64` and `System32` folders, yet the programs fail to detect them.

The programs in question are Steam (which despite the errors, still works, except for game updates) and CEMU (which doesn't open at all). I also hear the Windows "error sound" when turning off / restarting the computer, presumably due to those "missing" DLLs.

---

#### UPDATE

Even placing the DLLs directly beside the program and running it still causes errors.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first instinct was installing the Visual C++ Runtime
>   Redistributable, but this had no avail. After checking out the answers
>   above, I found later versions of it, but the result was the same. The
>   DLLs were appropriately placed by the installers in the SysWOW64 and
>   System32 folders, yet the programs fail to detect them.

You indicated you have VC++ 2010 and VC+ 2013 installed.  The programs in question require [VC++ 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

> As I said, I tried all combinations of plain 2010, 2010SP1 and
>   2010MFCSU for both 32 and 64 bit. The solution outlined in the linked
>   questions did not solve my issue.
>
> [image]

MSVCR110.dll and MSVCP110.dll are both components of [VC++ 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) not VC++ 2010